# Getting 401 when try to update user data in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I am sending a put request to update partial user data but I'm keep getting 401 even though I am passing the bearer token of admin.

code:

```
def update_user(user_id, user_data):
    import requests
    headers = dict()
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    data = {
        "grant_type": "password",
        "username": "admin",
        "password": os.getenv("KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_KEY"),
        "client_id": "admin-cli"
    }

    token = _request("POST", f"{server_internal_url}realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token", None, data=data).json()["access_token"]
    headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {token}"
    here = requests.put(admin_url+f"/users"+"/{user_id}".format(user_id=user_id), data=json.dumps(user_data),
                        headers=headers, verify=False)
    print(here)
```

Comment: Can you print the token value?

Comment: yes, I am getting the token.

Comment: https://keycloak:8443/auth/admin/realms/{realm_name}

Comment: https://keycloak:8443/auth/

Comment: {
      "username":"usama",
      "id":"997849e8-28be-4238-a0e5-f6d71d71fde2",
      "email":"usama.hameed@zeropoint.hr",
      "firstName":"changed",
      "lastName":"changed",
      "createdTimestamp":1640242211252
   }

Comment: above is user data

Comment: Remove the createdTimestamp. What happens when you do  here = requests.get(admin_url+f"/users", headers=headers, verify=False)

?

Comment: Get is working fine but PUT is giving 401.

Comment: This means that your user data is wrong, can you try send without the id and createdTimestamp